# Word for decision point

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word to fit the meaning "Groups together certain rules that determine one decision."

For example

- groups together those rules/considerations that determine a job-applicant's salary
- groups together those rules/considerations that determine a person's eligibility for a loan

Is "decision point" or "decision subject" a good word? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is the plural, [***criteria***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/criteria) (singular noun is *criterion*)

> A set of standards of judgments or criticisms; rules or principles for evaluating or testing something.

There is also ***[specifications](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/specification)*** as in *job specifications*

> A detailed description or assessment of requirements